# SwitchPreference default setting is always Off

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences, switchpreference

I have a SwitchPreference:

```
<SwitchPreference
android:key="@string/ground_guidance_halt_display_key"
android:title="@string/ground_guidance_halt_display_title" />
android:defaultValue="true"
```

No matter what I try, in the preference menu, it's always defaulted to OFF. Any ideas? I've also tried setting the default value to "On" instead to no avail. My other preference types' default values work correctly. I'm new enough to Android that I really don't know what else to post to help find an answer - sorry!

Comment: Is that code the actual formatting? (Having the tag close before `android:defaultValue`)

Comment: Oh my gosh, yes, that was the actual formatting...I will now hide in shame :/. Somewhere during my creation of my xml a copy/paste went wrong, haha. Solved.

Comment: Haha, no worries. It happens to the best of us.

Comment: Voting to close as "can no longer reproduce case"

Answer (score 1):

My XML formatting was off - unsure why no errors were thrown on runtime, but fixing it solved my problem.